# Three.js - Raycaster doesn't work properly on Ipad

Tags: ipad, mobile, three.js, raycasting, interaction

i had some issues with Raycaster when i tested my code on mobile device. I realised the same problem appears on the official examples on threejs.org when you activate tactile touch( ex: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=inter#webgl_interactive_cubes ). 
Is there an alternative to Raycaster to interact with objects in threejs ?

I am using Firefox 58.0.2 (64 bits) to test my three.js project and to simulate tactile touch.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't work because it has no listeners for [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the response,

In my example, i had to drag a panorama and interact with objects inside the panorama.
Here is the event listeners that works perfectly for me, if it can help others

```
function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {
    console.log("TouchStart")

    event.preventDefault();

    event.clientX = event.touches[0].pageX;
    event.clientY = event.touches[0].pageY;

    onDocumentMouseDown( event );
}

function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {
    console.log("TouchMove")

    if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      lon = ( onPointerDownPointerX - event.touches[0].pageX ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLon;
      lat = ( event.touches[0].pageY - onPointerDownPointerY ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLat;
    }
}

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    if ( isUserInteracting === true ) {
      lon = ( onPointerDownPointerX - event.clientX ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLon;
      lat = ( event.clientY - onPointerDownPointerY ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLat;
    }
}

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

  event.preventDefault();

  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

  if ( intersects.length > 0 && intersects[0].object.name.includes("sphere")) {
    INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;

   //some code

  isUserInteracting = true

  onPointerDownPointerX = event.clientX;
  onPointerDownPointerY = event.clientY;

  onPointerDownLon = lon;
  onPointerDownLat = lat;
}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an alternative to Raycaster to interact with objects in threejs ?

`Raycaster` does not add event listeners, that's application level code.

Many `three.js` examples only support mouse interaction. If you want to support touch devices, implement event listeners like `touchstart` and use the event information in order to perform a raycast.